# Rewrite Sales Order Print Block in magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm trying to rewrite sales order print block. to retrieve store vat number. But the field for the vat number is blank. this works fine when I create my function on the core.

here is my `config.xml`
app/code/local/Company/Sales/Block/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_print>Invent_Sales_Block_Order_Print</order_print>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

and here is my `print.php`

app/code/local/Company/Sales/Block/Order/Print.php
class Invent_Sales_Block_Order_Print extends Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Print

```
 public function getVatNumber()
    {
        $storeVAT = Mage::getStoreConfig("general/store_information/merchant_vat_number");

        return $storeVAT;
    }
```

here is my `print.phtml`

app/design/frontend/theme/package/template/sales/order/print.phtml

```
<?php echo "VAT Number:".' '.$this->getVatNumber(); ?>
```

Your help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I manged to fix this. I misplaced the etc directory. I placed in inside Block, instead of making it to be on the same level.

Thank you